# How to create advance query for 'randomize' result using elasticsearch

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch

I'm having a task to create a search using elasticsearch with custom result to show. I have a table that contain many fields, but these are the important fields: merchant, name, price.

the data is like this:

```
id  merchant   name   price
1   abc        aqua   3.50
2   abc        lorem  1.00
...
60  abc        ipsum  1.50
61  xyz        harley 2.00
62  xyz        barley 0.50
...
115 xyz        sweet  5.60
```

As you can see the ordering is by id, but the data merchant is stacked, the same merchant until several rows, then go to next merchant, also stacked.

So, the task is to show the rows but in different merchant every row. for example we have 4 different merchants, so the result should be

```
merchant   name     price
abc        ...      ...
def        ...      ...
ghi        ...      ...
xyz        ...      ...
abc        ...      ...  -->start with abc again
```

start with abc again, after all merchant showed once.

I'm having little experience in elasticsearch, i've read the documentation and want to know if that can be achieved using elasticsearch

Comment: I would recommend to just do it on the client side, to transform Elasticsearch response in an expected output format

Comment: ic, i will try any recommendation. thank you

Comment: You should be able to do this with some advanced script-based sorting

Comment: any hint of the advanced script-based sorting you mean? thanks

Comment: Here in docs https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-lang-spec.html