# Rearrange Object PHP

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch

I have a list of product objects, it look like this:

```
Product Object
(
    [id:private] => 1688115
    [categoryId:private] => 1
    [merchant:private] => theredshop
    [name:private] => Pepsi Max Cans 6 x 375mL
)
```

every fetch data, i fetch 15 record (Im using using ElasticSearch), for the 15 record the product order is by merchant name, so it will be 1 merchant stacked on top, then goes to next merchant.

What i want to do is to 'shuffle' the object result order to at least 1 merchant shows once then put another merchant next. for example, here my current result:

```
merchant    name
theredshop  pepsi
theredshop  lorem
theredshop  ipsum
```

what i want is

```
merchant    name
theredshop  pepsi
sevel       lorem
bluecircle  ipsum
```

I know how to arrange the result by looping and checking the merchant name that has been loaded. but how can i re arrange the object result back? or should i just recreate the object?

Comment: Do you assume the merchant name is always the first word of "name:private"?

Comment: no, fyi, merchant field is name of the merchant, name field is the product name field.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There are more than one product. It's not clear what you actually intend to do.

Comment: im trying to mix the result, the normal result that loaded is ordered by merchant. so if there are 15 merchants, you can say for example, the record 1-10 will be merchant A records, then record 11-17 will filled by merchant B record, and so on. what i want to achieve is: if there ae 15 merchants, the record #1 is record with merchant A, record #2 is record of merchant B, and so on until record #15, then record #16 will be a record of merchant A again, as all merchant already showed once, this repeats until all loaded

Comment: Rebuild your elasticsearch query...

Comment: And what about A:pepsi, B:pepsi, C:pepsi? As already mentioned such a task should be done in database.

Comment: doesnt matter, just want re- mix the merchant record

Comment: @Eakethet i m not sure how to do that, i asked the question already, if you in any chance know about ES, can you give me suggestion on my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585075/how-to-create-advance-query-for-randomize-result-using-elasticsearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a record table `$products` it can be written in PHP like that:

```
// restructure array as merchants having nested record sets
$merchants = [];
foreach(array_unique(array_column($products, 'merchant')) as $merchant)
  $merchants[$merchant] = array_values(array_filter($products, function($v)use($merchant){ return $v->merchant === $merchant;}));

// itererate over indexes up do max. products per merchant and a add a product of
// each merchant having a record with that index
$max_count = max(array_map(function($v){return count($v);}, $merchants));
$new_order = [];

for($i = 0; $i<$max_count; $i++)
  foreach ($merchants as $merchant)
    if($item = $merchant[$i] ?? false)
      $new_order[] = $item;


var_dump($new_order);
```

According to your comments you seem to have an object which you called "list" similar like that:

```
$products_object = (object)
  [
    (object)[
      'merchant' => 'theredshop',
      'name'     => 'pepsi',
    ],
    (object)[
      'merchant' => 'sevel',
      'name'     => 'pepsi',
    ],
    (object)[
      'merchant' => 'sevel',
      'name'     => 'lorem',
    ],

    (object)[
      'merchant' => 'sevel',
      'name'     => 'ipsum',
    ],

    (object)[
      'merchant' => 'bluecircle',
      'name'     => 'ipsum',
    ],

  ];
```

Convert it into an array first in order to operate with array functions on it:

```
$products = (array) $products_object;
```

Comment: hello, the products is an object, is that viable if still in object form?

Comment: @baycisk You speak about a "list" of objects. And yes, `array_column` does handle objects. I've tested against an array of objects. `$products =
[
  (object)[
    'merchant' => 'theredshop',
    'name'     => 'pepsi'
  ],
  (object)[
    'merchant' => 'sevel',
    'name'     => 'pepsi'
  ],
  (object)[
    'merchant' => 'sevel',
    'name'     => 'lorem'
  ],

  (object)[
    'merchant' => 'sevel',
    'name'     => 'ipsum'
  ],

  (object)[
    'merchant' => 'bluecircle',
    'name'     => 'ipsum'
  ],

];`

Comment: i tried but it said cannot handle object, it sad: Warning: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: @baycisk Parameter one is the `$products` array. It should be an array in order to be a "list". Use type cast `(array) $products`. The columns may remain objects since `array_column` does access properties of nested objects as columns.